# Qt on OSX Unresponsive widgets

Tags: c++, macos, qt

After successfully porting my Qt based windows application to OSX I noticed a problem. Widgets are behaving rather oddly, with not a single error being thrown and exactly the same code used on Windows.

Widgets, such as QTreeView and QListView, when clicked on show a blue border around them. When in this state that particular widget becomes unresponsive to clicks. That is until another widget is clicked on, becoming "active" with a blue border. When the first widget is clicked on (the non-active one) it reacts, but then gets a blue border and does not react to any input.

Other strange behavior, is when these widgets are popped out of the main application window, they stop rendering, as in you get a blank, floating window. When docked back into the main window they return to normal.

Since I cannot reproduce this behaviour on Windows with the identical code, it must be Qt on OSX, or OSX itself.

I have not a clue as to what is causing this.

By the way I am using Qt 5.0.2

I appreciate any and all help.

More info: I had'nt noticed this but I am getting the output `QBackingStore::flush() called with non-exposed window, behavior is undefined.`

I'm not sure if this is a result of my widgets disappearing out of there containing dock widget when undocked, or is the source of the problem

Comment: Try to create a small project and check if the issue still exists. If it does, post the code here.

Comment: I'm using Xcode by the way, and I tried to load up a qt example in xcode, but there was linker errors, so I did it in QtCreator and it worked absolutely perfectly. :( This is getting annoying

Comment: So there is something wrong in your code. Try to post some code that could be related to the issue.

Comment: I've actually fixed it, by upgrading to the latest dev version of Qt. It's probably a bug in Qt.

Comment: It's possible. I think you should post an answer and specify version you're using now.

Answer (score 1):

So you're all aware this was fixed by upgrading to Qt 5.1.0 beta.

I cannot explain why it just works when using a new version and  not with an older version. My own code between the two is identical.